# Can't clone project from Gitlab via ssh

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

can't clone project from the Gitlab via ssh.
This is my code from .gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
        - cd "C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\3W7xMYsb\0\user\erp_automation"
        - rm "C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\3W7xMYsb\0\user\erp_automation\Test"
        - mkdir "Test"
        - git clone http://gitlab-runner:$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY@git@git.skelia.local:user/erp_automation.git "C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\3W7xMYsb\0\user\erp_automation\Test"
        - echo "Test starts"
tests:
    tags:
        - shell
        - ci
    script:
        - mvn test
```

Get this error:
fatal: unable to access '$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY@git.skelia.local:user/erp_automation.git/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: welcome to SO! You don't use ssh private key in HTTPS, you use developer/private tokens... and if the error contains the $, it's not being evaluated.

Comment: error doesn't contain sign $, I replace my id_rsa to `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" in this message. 
I'm trying to clone my project via SSH, but I can't add right access data and I always get this error.

Comment: tried use access token but it didn't work

Comment: in the before_script you are using the `http` protocol, not `ssh`. Your url should start with `ssh://git@...` - see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: hm, thanks
But now I get this `Host key verification failed.`
I tried use `Personal Access Tokens`
Is it right?

Comment: hostkey is ssh, token is http... which one are you on now?

Comment: I changed to ssh://gitlab.skelia.local:token:@git...

Comment: to use ssh you first need to configure ssh from that shell. The command is `ssh -T git@git.skelia.local` and it will ask to accept the key: type "yes" to accept. If the key is not working, it's because your didnt upload the public key to gitlab first.

Comment: hi, sorry I didn't say that I use CI/CD and if I run this command in shell I will get

`ssh : The term 'ssh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script ``file, or operable program. Check the `
 `spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct ``and try again.`
 `At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script837562173\script.ps1:177 char:1`
 `+ ssh -T git@git.skelia.local`

Comment: SSH is part of "git for windows" package, that should be installed and available to the gitlab-runner user. If it's not in the path, use the full path, like `"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"`.

Comment: I always get this - https://prnt.sc/r3g3oe